# render json and return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How could we call `and return` after each `render json: @object` by default (automatically)

What I do now,

```
def not_authorized(msg="Not Authorized")
render json: msg, status: 401
end
```

In Controller call..

```
not_authorized and return
```

or

```
 render :json => @user and return
```

So..

1. Can we make `and return` implicit when calling render json?
2. Why isn't this the default i.e what's the purpose of not returning after a `render` or more specifically a `render json:`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ad 1. no, we can't - you have to explicitly declare it.

ad 2. keep in mind that controller is a regular class instance like any other within your app (User or whatever) and explicit return is a normal way to stop method execution earlier than last line. The only solution would be to use `exceptions` or `throw-catch` blocks, however it always has performance impact.